# Girsanov transformation brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

If you have a SDE say:

$dX = \mu dt + \sigma d W$,

where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are not necessarily constant. Say, this process corresponds to a probability $P$. If you apply a Girsanov transformation and obtain a process $d\hat{X}$, under a new probability $\hat{P}$, is this new probability density **always** that of a Brownian motion density? I.e,. something like:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{t} \sqrt{2 \pi}} exp \left[-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^2\right] dx$,

where this is the density of $d\hat{W}(t)$ at $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Unless $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are deterministic, there is no reason to expect that the distribution of $X$ will be Gaussian under $P$. By the same token, if $\mu$ and $\sigma$ *are* deterministic but the drift of $W$ under $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$ is not (and there is no guarantee it will be deterministic) then $X$ is unlikely to be Gaussian under $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$.